# Can't open photoshop's script with .bat file

Tags: javascript, batch-file, exe, photoshop, psd

I try to open a script (.js) in photoshop, with a .bat like that:

```
    start Grass_Texture.psd
    start Photoshop.exe ScriptPhotoshopGrass.js
```

Photoshop start but he don't execute ScriptPhotoshopGrass.js,

if it can help you, i have try to open Grass_Texture.psd like that:

```
   start Photoshop.exe Grass_Texture.psd
```

and i have the same problem, photoshop run alone,

Help me please

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution

I have change

```
start Photoshop.exe ScriptPhotoshopGrass.js
```

to

```
start Photoshop.exe "%CD%\ScriptPhotoshopGrass.js"
```